# Paypal Checkout error: "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

Tags: php, laravel

I create paypal order on frontend (javascript) and get orderId and payerId:

```
createOrder: async (data, actions) => {
          const item = await this.fetchPaypalItem()
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [
              {
                description: item.description,
                amount: {
                  value: item.description,
                }
              }
            ]
          })
      },
```

I receive orderId and payerId i checked.
On server side(Laravel) i am using official library https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK and i am geting error when i am trying to create order (from paypal documentation) like this:

```
public function createOrder(Request $request){

        $request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
        $request->prefer('return=representation');
        $request->body = self::buildRequestBody();
       // 3. Call PayPal to set up a transaction
        $client = PayPalClient::client();
        $response = $client->execute($request);
        return response()->json($response);

}
```

I checked and $client object is empty object. I was checking my credentials but there is no problem because it is working on the javascript.

I changed one line in HttpClient class of that official library:
$curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true); => $curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
And now it is working but i am afraid it's not secure. Any solution for that problem and is it safe like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an error with curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_CAINFO, null). It was not sertificated... in official sdk, i downloaded cacert.pem file and switched its path with null and now is working when CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER is set to true.